# Delphi validate database fields before TEdit exit

Tags: validation, delphi, field

I've a strange question I tought about for exercise that is not easy to explicate.

Suppose I've a form with some TDBEdit object. Nturally every TDBEdit object reference a database field.
Here a simple example:

[image]

When the user click the save button (the little disk icon on the top of the image) I make the data validation and, if data are correct, I register them into the database. Simple!

But my mental exercise is this:
all my data tables are included in a datamodule so what about if I would like to trasfer the data validation from the form to the datamodule?
Simple... it's enough to validate the table fields like this:

```
  if (fAut_Cognome.Value = '') or (fAut_Nome.Value = '') then begin
    ...
    Give error messsage
    ...
  end;
```

But If the user doesn't leave the last TDBEdit object the relative database field is not valorized (for example while adding a new record to the table the database field will ane no value).
So my question is this: there is a way to validate data, from datamodule, even if the user doesn't leave the TDBEdit control?

Comment: Does it make a difference if validation is on the module or the form?

Comment: Yes, because if the validation in on the datamodule I can decouple it from the form.

Comment: I mean the problem. You don't have the "not leaving the dbedit" problem when validation is on the form, but you have the problem when validation is on the data module. Is that correct? ... Ok, I get it now. On the form you read control's value, on data module you read field value.

Comment: Yes it is. In the form I can check the TDBEdit controls for the validation

Comment: Exactly! You are right Sertac

Comment: You should be able to use OnBeforePost of the table to do the validation, all field's should have their values. 'Abort' when validation fails. Additionally for field level validation, fields have OnValidate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125006/discussion-between-eros-and-sertac-akyuz).

Answer (score 0):

You should plug the `OnBeforeExit` event of your TDBEdit to a method in the Datamodule. But as said in comments you will only test the control's value, not the DB field's value because not updated yet.